# Scikit Learn transform method - manual calculation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transform, pca

I have a question about Scikit-Learn's PCA [transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform) method. The code is found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L741) - scroll down to find the `transform()` method.

They show the procedure in this [simple example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-incremental-pca-py) - the procedure is to first fit and then transform:

```
pca.fit(X) #step 1: fit()
X_transformed = fast_dot(X, self.components_.T) #step 2: transform()
```

I am trying to do this manually as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.utils.extmath import fast_dot

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

pca = PCA(n_components=3)

pca.fit(X)

Xm = X.mean(axis=1)
print pca.transform(X)[:5,:] #Method 1 - expected
X = X - Xm[None].T # or can use X = X - Xm[:, np.newaxis]
print fast_dot(X,pca.components_.T)[:5,:] #Method 2 - manual
```

Expected:

```
[[-2.68420713 -0.32660731  0.02151184]
 [-2.71539062  0.16955685  0.20352143]
 [-2.88981954  0.13734561 -0.02470924]
 [-2.7464372   0.31112432 -0.03767198]
 [-2.72859298 -0.33392456 -0.0962297 ]]
```

Manual

```
[[-0.98444292 -2.74509617  2.28864171]
 [-0.75404746 -2.44769323  2.35917528]
 [-0.89110797 -2.50829893  2.11501947]
 [-0.74772562 -2.33452022  2.10205674]
 [-1.02882877 -2.75241342  2.17090017]]
```

As you can see, the two results are different. Is there a step missing somewhere in the `transform()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a great expert on PCA, but by looking at the sklearn source code I found your problem - you take the mean along the wrong axis.

Here's the solution:

```
Xm = X.mean(axis=0)  # Axis 0 instead of 1
print pca.transform(X)[:5,:] #Method 1 - expected
X = X - Xm  # No need for transpose now
print fast_dot(X,pca.components_.T)[:5,:] #Method 2 - manual
```

Results:

```
[[-2.68420713  0.32660731 -0.02151184]
 [-2.71539062 -0.16955685 -0.20352143]
 [-2.88981954 -0.13734561  0.02470924]
 [-2.7464372  -0.31112432  0.03767198]
 [-2.72859298  0.33392456  0.0962297 ]]
[[-2.68420713  0.32660731 -0.02151184]
 [-2.71539062 -0.16955685 -0.20352143]
 [-2.88981954 -0.13734561  0.02470924]
 [-2.7464372  -0.31112432  0.03767198]
 [-2.72859298  0.33392456  0.0962297 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Was this posted somewherre - `axis=0`?

Comment: I saw it in the source code: `self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)` in sklearn.decomposition.pca